# Trying to print words in a file with C child processes

Tags: c, unix, fork

The goal is to create a child process for each word in a file, and have the child process print the word.  The file only has the following five words, each one on a separate line:

```
Aachen
Biscay
Capri
Dino
Ellis
```

The problem is that when I try to print to a file, I get one of the words printing twice.

```
Aachen
Ellis
Biscay
Capri
Ellis
Dino
```

Here is the code.  It seems pretty straight forward, but I can't figure out why I am getting the extra word.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char word[50];
  int i;
  pid_t p;

  while (fscanf(stdin, "%s", word) != EOF) {
    i = 0;
    while (i < sizeof(word)) {
      if (word[i] < 'A' || word[i] > 'z') {
        word[i] = '\0';
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }

    p = fork();

    if (p != 0) 
      continue;

    break;
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", word);

  return 0;
}
```

I run the program as follows:

$ ./printwords < words2.txt > out.txt

Comment: I tried adding 
  if (p == 0)
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", word); to the print statement in case the parent is responsible for the double printing, but now it prints only four words.

Comment: It's been a while since I've messed with this so forgive me if I'm wrong, but for debugging, try also printing the `pid_t`. That should show who is printing what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The father is also printing the last word in the very end.  Try this instead of printing *after* the loop:

```
if (p == 0) {
  fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", word);
}
else {
  continue;
}
```

Comment: I ran into a problem.  If I run the program against a much larger file of about 99k words, it only prints about 31k of them.  I have no idea why it would only print about 1/3rd of the words when running against a larger file?

Comment: Probably because forking processes like hell typically fails when there are too many already running.  Check the return value for being below zero to notice that (as another answer here already proposes).

Comment: I added an else for pid values < 0 to write "Fork failed." but I am not seeing any of those messages. 
    if (p != 0) 
      break;
    else if (p < 0) {
      fprintf(stdout, "Fork failed.\n");
      fflush(stdout);      
      continue;
    }

Comment: It keeps just printing some random section of the words, I have no idea why.

Comment: Yeah, if many processes are writing to the same stream (your tty), depending on the OS internal code and their own buffering they could overwrite each other, at least intermingle or garble up each other.  Doing that is never a decent approach.  But, come on, forking for printing isn't a real application anyway, is it?

Comment: The end goal is to read a file & print out he words in alphabetic order, counting duplicates, all using child processes.  If I can't even get the program to spawn children to print the words unsorted & uncounted, I have no idea how I am going to do all three.

Comment: Okay, but you won't actually start one process for each word then.

Comment: I really have no idea how to accomplish the goal.  How many words per process should I be using?  Should I read in 5, 10 or 500 words at a time?  What would be the best approach?

Comment: I think you could maybe use one process for sorting (probably just using the Unix `sort`) and one for removing the duplicates (print only if line is different from the one before).

Comment: What is the specific language of the assignment? Does it tell you how to use the child processes?  The task of reading and sorting data does not require any forking or child processes.

Comment: The language is C on Linux.  It would be far easier if I didn't have to use child processes, but the whole goal of the otherwise vague assignment is to use subprocesses.

Comment: @user2227422: if you have the code `if (p != 0) break; else if (p < 0) {...` the second test will never be true, as if p is negative, the first test will be true and break before you even get to the second if.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf adds a null terminator to the string automatically when you use %s, so you can remove this entire section from your code:

```
i = 0;
while (i < sizeof(word)) 
{
    if (word[i] < 'A' || word[i] > 'z') 
    {
        word[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Here is a solution I found that worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char word[50];
    int i;
    pid_t p;

    while (fscanf(stdin, "%s", word) != EOF) 
    {

        p = fork();
        if (p != 0)
            break; //this will allow the parent process to exit the loop    

        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", word);
        fflush(stdout);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is necessary to flush the output buffer before forking again. If you fork before the output buffer flushes the child process will also inherit that output buffer which will result in duplication.

Comment: I tried your exact code, but I am still getting only about 1/3rd of the words printing from the larger 99k word file.

Comment: try also flushing stdin before you fork with fflush(stdin);

Comment: And if that doesn't work it probably makes more sense to do your task using open() and read() instead of io streams.

Comment: The assignment has to use stdio & stdin

Answer (score 0):

```
// remove pid_t p; attribution in the beginning then:

pid_t = fork();

if( pid_t == 0){
// here we're a child process. put your worker code here

}
else if (pid_t < 0){
printf("Fork failed!");

exit(1);
}
else { // here we're parent process

}
```